# REST - basic principles - Where to put the new and edit words

Tags: rest

I'm wondering where to put the edit, and new keywords by rest application. I'll use express-resource in a project, and the default settings are these:

```
GET     /forums              ->  index
GET     /forums/new          ->  new
POST    /forums              ->  create
GET     /forums/:forum       ->  show
GET     /forums/:forum/edit  ->  edit
PUT     /forums/:forum       ->  update
DELETE  /forums/:forum       ->  destroy
```

There is a problem with this solution: there is not a real resource behind the new and edit. I mean the URL-s refer to resources, and after any slash is a sub-resource.

For example:`http://my.example.com/users/1` represents:

```
var firstUser = {
   name: "John Smith",
   birthDate: new Date(1952,10,4),
   hobbies: ["skiing", "football"],
   ...
}
```

And `http://my.example.com/users/1/birthDate` represents:

```
firstUser.birthDate
```

But by `http://my.example.com/users/1/edit` there is no such property:

```
firstUser.edit
```

So something is wrong with this conception.

Where is the real place of these keywords? In queryString or in headers?

Comment: What kind of Represenation shall `GET /forums/new` produce?

Comment: Nothing. I mean there is no data behind that url. Maybe the scheme of the forums table. I think the GET /forums?new would be a better solution. Btw how to colorize code in comments? :D

Comment: Hmm, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432660/how-to-edit-a-resource edit: watched, not a duplicate, but the answer contains this: "The URL always represents the resource, not the action. Thus, while mysite/resource_one/edit might be a proper URL to a page that initiates editing a resource..."

Comment: So according to this, the /edit page can be an editing resource the /new page can be a creation resource or so. I'm not convinced. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the perspective of a REST API these do not exist anywhere as they are not related to the representation of resources.  They are actions upon resources and therefore expressed by the HTTP methods used.  They would not bee needed if you were to create an external client that uses the API.

There is likely a need to provide some support for this type of functionality so that something like a UI could be presented, but that is the concern of the particular application and not the API itself.  At that point it becomes discretionary but I would certainly avoid using headers as that would be pretty outside of conventional practice.  But by headers it appears that you actually meant URI path.  Out of those 2 I would say the path is the better option since it clearly defines any type of UI as a distinct resource and would keep it apart from the clean API, while using a query string on a part of the API would more tightly (mistakenly) associate it with the underlying resource.

Comment: If they were actions they should be methods like GET, POST etc... But they are not. They are just different representation forms of the same resource if they are separated from the original representation form.

Comment: are they different representations of the Model or are they different Views?

Comment: In which context? :D If the Model is the resource behind the REST API, then they are different View-s with the same MIME type, and the best option is to separate them with an extra header. I think it was just a misunderstanding, I was talking about the ListView, CreationView, View, EditableView,  of the Collection and Model, and not the POST and PUT methods which are called by sending the form data of the CreationView and EditableView. If you send only the data in a serialized format you have those views on client side, and your REST API don't have such problems because it sends only JSON.

Comment: It doesn't sound like a misunderstanding.  What I'm saying is that those Views don't fall under the umbrella of the API and therefore are not covered by the same concepts.  They should be exposed under different paths rather than simply using headers or query parameters so that it is clear that they are not part of the API.  Or to directly respond to your comment: your **API** shouldn't have the issue no matter where it is.  Just because the implementation may co-habitate with it doesn't mean that it should pollute it.

Comment: And headers are normally for things more along the lines of metadata and request information.  Using them to signal logical changes in the body certainly does not seem standard.

Comment: Yes and no. I mean the REST API has the potential to provide different presentation of the resources, so it can provide html with different layouts too, not just a data serialization format. It's just easier to separate the client from the data provider. This problem occurs by a simple data provider application too: Imagine a REST service which provides JSON and knows how many money people have, and you ask from this application how many money I have. GET /ppl/inf3rno/money. You'll have the number in HUF, not in USD. If you want USD you have to send a request header: currency-format: USD...

Comment: "And headers are normally for things more along the lines of metadata and request information. Using them to signal logical changes in the body certainly does not seem standard." - accept: text/html, accept: application/json, if-modified-since... They all modify the body and they are all standard...

Comment: Yes, and all of those are metadata that refer to how the body should be parsed and retrieved or the response sent.  None of them apply at all to logical changes within the body, or any changes after the processing would have begun.  They are all external to the Model that the body represents.

Comment: And things like content negotiation still are not *logical* changes. So far examples you've mentioned do not change the intent of the URL as you're looking to do.  Overall I'm a little confused...why did you ask the question if you already have such strong opinions?

Comment: Yepp now I have, but I had to think about in the last 2 days... Btw I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664857/spring-mvc-rest-different-layout-with-same-content with the same duplicated layout problem, and they solved a similar way.

Comment: Yes, and reading the comments it is established that they are talking about addressing alternate clients but for the same intent, and this type of use is called abuse with no argument.  From a practical standpoint writing business logic that is concerned with headers defeats all of the simplicity that REST offers.  Headers should be at a lower level than application code.

Comment: It is not necessary by every application, just in special cases like these... Creating separated clients is much easier, but you cannot do that in every case.

Comment: You described well, that the client is not the part of the REST API, it's a different application which uses the REST service. I did not understand it until now. Thx! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Some update after a year or so:

- edit and new should be hyperlinks

  - these links are just the representations of possible operation calls
  - by following them it is possible to manipulate the resource they belong by sending representations of the intended resource state, and/or by calling the proper methods
- these terms are no resources, they don't have their own URL (resource identifier)

Thanks the advices Matt Whipple!

I think the best way to learn REST is reading the [Fielding dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm). There are many tutorials out there, but the authors of most of these does not really understand REST.